# How to find numbers that are dividable with 2, 3 or 5 in max 1 second

Tags: java, numbers

I need your help guys with this specific question.

***How many numbers*** from an interval a <= b [1, 10^18] are dividable by ***2, 3 or 5?***

**Result must be run in max 1 sec!**

A standard program would use a for loop seen bellow.

```
a = 1;
b = 1000000000
results = 0;

for (int i = a; i <= b; i++){
    if (i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0, i % 5 == 0){
        results++;
    }
}
System.out.println(results);
```

But if I enter high numbers, my program need a lot of time to give me the results.

**Example 1:**

a = 11, b = 30, result = 14

**Example 2:**

a = 123456789012345678, b = 876543210987654321
, result = 552263376115226339

Comment: Compile or Runtime ?

Comment: In example2 a is equal to b, is that correct?

Comment: @kaos My bad, I corrected the exaple

Comment: @GamerzX you can also correct sample program because it will not compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something like that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long a = 123456789012345678L, b = 876543210987654321L;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    long score = getCount(b) - getCount(a - 1);

    System.out.println("Time: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start)));
    System.out.println("Divisible by 2 or 3 or 5: " + score);
}

public static long getCount(long end) {
    return (end / 2) + (end / 3) + (end / 5) - ((end / 6)  + (end / 10) + (end / 15)) + (end / 30);
}
```

The solution:

- It counts how many numbers are divisible by 2 or 3 or 5 separately and sums that.
- Now we need to discard numbers that where counted twice: for 2 and 3 it will be every 6th number, for 2 and 5 every 10th number, for 3 and 5 every 15th number
- At the end we need to include numbers that are divisible by 2 and 3 and 5 that where discarded in step 2 so we add every 30th number.

Comment: @StackFlowed Could you point a case when the result is wrong?

Comment: @kaos I can give you some correct results as examples. Check the updated thread above for those examples...

Comment: @kaos Does it give the right answer, because why is there an "L" at the end of both a and b variables? And why is there a-1 involved?

Comment: @GamerzX a - 1 is necessary to include first value in computation. L is for defining variables as longs. It gives correct results for your examples and other that i did.

Comment: @kaos Thank you very much, did not think the answer is so simple, with a bit of mathemathical thinking :) btw do I allways have to reffer with "@" to you so you can see the notification? (im new around here :))

Comment: You don't have to use '@'. It's useful when there are more people involved in conversation. So i didn't have to use it here ;). You can accept the answer if you think it's good (or wait for another that could be better :).